# How to execute External Tool in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

Where can I actually launch an external tool in IntelliJ?

I know where to set up the external tool, and I've that done, but I cannot see where to launch it anywhere!

I don't see it from the Run menu, nor from any right-click menu.

Comment: May I ask what the tool is? Or at least how you typically run it?

Comment: Its just an external Java jar file that I am running using java.exe -jar etc..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can run anything from the command line using the Command Line Tool Support plugin from JetBrains. See details [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6630-command-line-tool-support).

Answer (score 6):

On menu *Tools* ⮕ *External Tools*:
[image]

Comment: Worth noting that you first have to add the external tool via [settings > external tools] before it appers on the menu (or before the menu item even appears).  https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-third-party-tools.html

Answer (score 2):

In IntelliJ IDEA, in your run/test configurations (Run -> Edit Configurations) you have the choice of running an external tool 'before launch'. You can do this by opening up the run configuration menu, creating a new run configuration, and, down the bottom, adding a 'Run External Tool' option.

You can then add an external tool to be ran upon launch. You can run other programs or execute command line commands.

When you want to run the external tool, simply click the run button up the top of IntelliJ's main screen. If you want the external tool to run without the project compiling, simply remove the 'Make Project' and run project in the run configuration.