# How do I use sops as an External Tool in my IDE?

Tags: intellij-idea, mozilla-sops

I'd like to use [sops](https://github.com/mozilla/sops) to edit files in my IDE (Intellij), but I'm not sure how best to set it up as an External Tool.

I found these related questions:

- [Use vscode as editor for sops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52374634/use-vscode-as-editor-for-sops)
- [How to execute External Tool in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19471909/how-to-execute-external-tool-in-intellij)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA has no support for `--wait` and cannot be used via the `EDITOR` environment.

See [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-152266) and the linked duplicates.

External tool will not work. This can be supported by implementing IntelliJ IDEA plug-in that will integrate with the command line tool to transparently encrypt/decrypt the files you are editing.

Answer (score 3):

IntelliJ IDEA at least 2020.2 does now support `--wait`

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-the-ide-features-from-command-line.html#arguments

I tried

```sh
export EDITOR="idea --wait"
sops secret.yaml
```

<del>Unfortunately doesn't work even though in idea there is the message</del>

`Activated from command line: Command line will be waiting until the file '/Users/user/Development/../secret.yaml' has been closed.`

Comment: I tried it again a year later with 2021.01 and it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2020.3.2 i can confirm that setting environment EDITOR to

```
"C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\GoLand 2020.3.2\\bin\\goland.exe" --wait
```

and then using sops <file.enc.yaml> works fine for me (in windows). You need to press Ctrl-S each time you want changes to be saved since opened file treated as external for the project you working with.